# Laravel calculating totals based on hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `Affiliate` model with a `AffiliateSummaryStat` statistic model which contains aggregated totals for each hour of the day and linked by `affiliate_id`. I need to be able to return a single `AffiliateSummaryStat` but with the sum of each model. How can I achieve this?

Here's my relationship right now, this is my `Affiliate` model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class Affiliate extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'affiliates';

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'allow_submission' => 'boolean',
        'is_favourited' => 'boolean',
        'is_default' => 'boolean',
        'is_enabled' => 'boolean',
        'last_used_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'api_key',
    ];

    /**
     * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'is_deleting',
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if we're editing the model
     */
    public function getIsDeletingAttribute(): bool
    {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Get the affiliate summary stats
     */
    public function affiliate_summary_stats()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AffiliateSummaryStat::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the commissions for the affiliate
     */
    public function commissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Commission::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the affiliate products for this model.
     */
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AffiliateProduct::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the splits for this affiliate
     */
    public function splits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(AffiliateSplit::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the applications for this affiliate
     */
    public function applications()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Application::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the company that owns the model.
     */
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the model.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        // on create
        static::created(function ($model) {
            Cache::tags('affiliates')->flush();
        });

        // on update
        static::updated(function ($model) {
            Cache::tags('affiliates')->flush();
        });
    }
}
```

And is used in my controller:

```php
$report = Affiliate::with([
    'affiliate_summary_stats'
])->select([
    'id', 'aff_id', 'description', 'last_used_at'
])->get();
```

MY current output:

```json
{
    "model": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "aff_id": "aff107",
            "description": "Default system affiliate",
            "last_used_at": null,
            "is_deleting": false,
            "affiliate_summary_stats": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "affiliate_id": 1,
                    "brand": null,
                    "campaign": "B",
                    "total_sessions": 2,
                    "total_submits": 0,
                    "total_leads": 0,
                    "total_accepted": 0,
                    "total_declined": 0,
                    "total_redirected": 0,
                    "logged_at": "2023-03-21T08:00:00.000000Z",
                    "created_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:33.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:33.000000Z",
                    "total_sessions_formatted": "2",
                    "total_submits_formatted": "0",
                    "total_leads_formatted": "0",
                    "total_accepted_formatted": "0",
                    "total_declined_formatted": "0",
                    "total_redirected_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate": 0,
                    "conversion_rate_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate_formatted_with_symbol": "0%"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "affiliate_id": 1,
                    "brand": null,
                    "campaign": "A",
                    "total_sessions": 2,
                    "total_submits": 0,
                    "total_leads": 0,
                    "total_accepted": 0,
                    "total_declined": 0,
                    "total_redirected": 0,
                    "logged_at": "2023-03-21T08:00:00.000000Z",
                    "created_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:36.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:36.000000Z",
                    "total_sessions_formatted": "2",
                    "total_submits_formatted": "0",
                    "total_leads_formatted": "0",
                    "total_accepted_formatted": "0",
                    "total_declined_formatted": "0",
                    "total_redirected_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate": 0,
                    "conversion_rate_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate_formatted_with_symbol": "0%"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "affiliate_id": 1,
                    "brand": null,
                    "campaign": null,
                    "total_sessions": 3,
                    "total_submits": 3,
                    "total_leads": 3,
                    "total_accepted": 3,
                    "total_declined": 0,
                    "total_redirected": 0,
                    "logged_at": "2023-03-21T08:00:00.000000Z",
                    "created_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:39.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-21T08:56:04.000000Z",
                    "total_sessions_formatted": "3",
                    "total_submits_formatted": "3",
                    "total_leads_formatted": "3",
                    "total_accepted_formatted": "3",
                    "total_declined_formatted": "0",
                    "total_redirected_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate": 100,
                    "conversion_rate_formatted": "100.00",
                    "conversion_rate_formatted_with_symbol": "100.00%"
                },
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "affiliate_id": 1,
                    "brand": null,
                    "campaign": "A",
                    "total_sessions": 2,
                    "total_submits": 0,
                    "total_leads": 0,
                    "total_accepted": 0,
                    "total_declined": 0,
                    "total_redirected": 0,
                    "logged_at": "2023-03-21T08:00:00.000000Z",
                    "created_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:36.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2023-03-21T08:47:36.000000Z",
                    "total_sessions_formatted": "2",
                    "total_submits_formatted": "0",
                    "total_leads_formatted": "0",
                    "total_accepted_formatted": "0",
                    "total_declined_formatted": "0",
                    "total_redirected_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate": 0,
                    "conversion_rate_formatted": "0",
                    "conversion_rate_formatted_with_symbol": "0%"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "aff_id": "aff4000",
            "description": "Old",
            "last_used_at": null,
            "is_deleting": false,
            "affiliate_summary_stats": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i think you can simply use withSum function in laravel:
here is a link https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions

Answer (score 0):

If i am solving this my way i would do the following
First create an appends attribute to store your AffiliateSummaryStat,

```
class Affiliate extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['total_summary_stats'];

    public function getTotalSummaryStatsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->affiliate_summary_stats()
            ->selectRaw('SUM(total_sessions) as total_sessions_sum')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(total_submits) as total_submits_sum')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(total_leads) as total_leads_sum')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(total_accepted) as total_accepted_sum')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(total_declined) as total_declined_sum')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(total_redirected) as total_redirected_sum')
            ->first()
            ->toArray();
    }

    // ...
}
```

I am just giving you another way you can achieve this. If there is a better way, lets wait for the right answer and we will both learn from it